# PyMOL get the name of selected protein

Tags: python, bioinformatics, pymol

So I'm using a PyMOL script to find the surface residues on a protein (found at http://www.pymolwiki.org/index.php/FindSurfaceResidues).  And I need it to write a text file containing the name of the protein that is currently selected in the PyMOL session.  As far as I've searched, I can't find a PyMOL command to get the name of the selected protein.  Does anyone with more experience with PyMOL have an idea on how to accomplish this?

Thanks

code:

```
'''
http://pymolwiki.org/index.php/FindSurfaceResidues
'''

from __future__ import print_function
from pymol import cmd


def findSurfaceAtoms(selection="all", cutoff=2.5, quiet=1):
    """
DESCRIPTION

    Finds those atoms on the surface of a protein
    that have at least 'cutoff' exposed A**2 surface area.

USAGE

    findSurfaceAtoms [ selection, [ cutoff ]]

SEE ALSO

    findSurfaceResidues
    """
    cutoff, quiet = float(cutoff), int(quiet)

    tmpObj = cmd.get_unused_name("_tmp")
    cmd.create(tmpObj, "(" + selection + ") and polymer", zoom=0)

    cmd.set("dot_solvent", 1, tmpObj)
    cmd.get_area(selection=tmpObj, load_b=1)

    # threshold on what one considers an "exposed" atom (in A**2):
    cmd.remove(tmpObj + " and b < " + str(cutoff))

    selName = cmd.get_unused_name("exposed_atm_")
    cmd.select(selName, "(" + selection + ") in " + tmpObj)

    cmd.delete(tmpObj)

    if not quiet:
        print("Exposed atoms are selected in: " + selName)

    return selName


def findSurfaceResidues(selection="all", cutoff=2.5, doShow=0, quiet=1):
    """
DESCRIPTION

    Finds those residues on the surface of a protein
    that have at least 'cutoff' exposed A**2 surface area.

USAGE

    findSurfaceResidues [ selection, [ cutoff, [ doShow ]]]

ARGUMENTS

    selection = string: object or selection in which to find exposed
    residues {default: all}

    cutoff = float: cutoff of what is exposed or not {default: 2.5 Ang**2}

RETURNS

    (list: (chain, resv ) )
        A Python list of residue numbers corresponding
        to those residues w/more exposure than the cutoff.

    """
    cutoff, doShow, quiet = float(cutoff), int(doShow), int(quiet)

    selName = findSurfaceAtoms(selection, cutoff, quiet)

    exposed = set()
    cmd.iterate(selName, "exposed.add((chain,resv))", space=locals())

    selNameRes = cmd.get_unused_name("exposed_res_")
    cmd.select(selNameRes, "byres " + selName)

    if not quiet:
        print("Exposed residues are selected in: " + selNameRes)

    if doShow:
        cmd.show_as("spheres", "(" + selection + ") and polymer")
        cmd.color("white", selection)
        cmd.color("yellow", selNameRes)
        cmd.color("red", selName)

    return sorted(exposed)

cmd.extend("findSurfaceAtoms", findSurfaceAtoms)
cmd.extend("findSurfaceResidues", findSurfaceResidues)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [get_names](http://www.pymolwiki.org/index.php/Get_Names) function.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I am getting OP question ,right, modified code to have it write a
`surface.txt` file listing the name of the surfaced protein/object on which the `findSurfaceResidues()` runs against with the list of residues composing the surface and a `surface.pdb` file listing all the atoms involed in the surface. I had to change the doShow part of the original script, because I was not able to feed selections to the `findSurfaceResidues` command.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pymol import cmd, stored

def my_save(file,object,header):

    # make sure there's a newline after the header

    suff = "" if header[-1]=='\n' else '\n'

    f = open(file, 'w')

    # write the header

    f.write("################\n##"+ header+suff+"################\n")

    # write the PDB

     f.write(cmd.get_pdbstr(object))

     f.close()

def findSurfaceAtoms(selection = "all", cutoff = 2.5, quiet = 1):
    """
    DESCRIPTION

    Finds those atoms on the surface of a protein
    that have at least 'cutoff' exposed A**2 surface area.

    USAGE

    findSurfaceAtoms [ selection, [ cutoff ]]

    SEE ALSO

    findSurfaceResidues

    """
    
    #REMOVE WATERS HOH
    cmd.select('all_waters', 'resn HOH')
    
    cmd.remove('all_waters')
    


    cutoff, quiet = float(cutoff), int(quiet)

    tmpObj = cmd.get_unused_name("_tmp")
    
        
    cmd.create(tmpObj, "(" + selection + ") and polymer", zoom=0)
        


    cmd.set("dot_solvent", 1, tmpObj)
    cmd.get_area(selection=tmpObj, load_b=1)

    # threshold on what one considers an "exposed" atom (in A**2):
    cmd.remove(tmpObj + " and b < " + str(cutoff))

    selName = cmd.get_unused_name("exposed_atm_")
    cmd.select(selName, "(" + selection + ") in " + tmpObj)

    cmd.delete(tmpObj)

    if not quiet:
        print("Exposed atoms are selected in: " + selName)
        
        print("cmd.get_names('objects',  1 ,selection) : ", cmd.get_names('objects',  1 ,selection))
        
        print("cmd.get_names(,  1 ,selection) : ", cmd.get_names('selections',  1 ,selection))


    print('selName : ', selName , type(selName))
    
    return selName


def findSurfaceResidues(selection="all", cutoff=2.5, doShow=0, quiet=1):
    """
    DESCRIPTION

    Finds those residues on the surface of a protein
    that have at least 'cutoff' exposed A**2 surface area.

    USAGE

    findSurfaceResidues [ selection, [ cutoff, [ doShow ]]]

    ARGUMENTS

    selection = string: object or selection in which to find exposed
    residues {default: all}

    cutoff = float: cutoff of what is exposed or not {default: 2.5 Ang**2}

    RETURNS

    (list: (chain, resv ) )
        A Python list of residue numbers corresponding
        to those residues w/more exposure than the cutoff.

    """
    
    cutoff, doShow, quiet = float(cutoff), int(doShow), int(quiet)

    selName = findSurfaceAtoms(selection, cutoff, quiet)

    exposed = set()
    
    cmd.iterate(selName, "exposed.add((chain,resv))", space=locals())

    selNameRes = cmd.get_unused_name("exposed_res_")
    cmd.select(selNameRes, "byres " + selName)

    if not quiet:
        print("Exposed residues are selected in: " + selNameRes)

    if doShow:
        
        print('------------------DO SHOW -------')
        
        # cmd.show_as("spheres", "(" + selection + ") and polymer")
        
        cmd.show_as("spheres",   selection + " and polymer")
        
        cmd.color("white", selection)
        cmd.color("yellow", selNameRes)
        cmd.color("red", selName)


    print_locals(selNameRes)

    return sorted(exposed)

cmd.extend("findSurfaceAtoms", findSurfaceAtoms)
cmd.extend("findSurfaceResidues", findSurfaceResidues)



def print_locals(sele):
    """
    
    SALVA TUTTI I RESIDUI  CHE COMPONGONO LA SELZIONE
    
    SAVE NAMES OF ALL RESIDUES IN THE SELECTION
    
    """
    
    stored.residues = dict()
    
    print('---------------------> ', cmd.get_names('objects', 1 , sele))
    
    for _name in cmd.get_names('objects', 1 , sele):
    
        stored.residues[_name] = []
    
    
    #CMD.ITERATE 1
    cmd.iterate(sele, "stored.residues[model].append((resv, resn))")
    
    
    #CMD.ITERATE 2
    # cmd.iterate(sele, "stored.residues[model].append((resv, resn, [type, index, name]))")  ## !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! FARE QJUI
    
    # print(stored.residues)
    
    ## THIS BLOCK WORKS ONLY WITH CMD.ITERATE 1
    for _i in stored.residues:
        
        b = list(dict.fromkeys(stored.residues.get(_i)))
        
        stored.residues[_i] = b
    
    
    with open('surfaces.txt', 'w') as _handle:
        
        for _i in stored.residues:
            
            _handle.write(_i+'\n')
            
            # CMD.ITERATE 1
            _handle.writelines([str(_a[0]).ljust(6) + str(_a[1].rjust(10))+'\n' for _a in stored.residues[_i]])
            
            #CMD.ITERATE 2
            # _handle.writelines([str(_a[0]).ljust(6) + str(_a[1].rjust(10)) + '   '.join(str(item) for item in [i for i in _a[2]]).rjust(40)+ '\n' for _a in stored.residues[_i]])
            
            _handle.write('------------------------------------------------------\n')
    

        
    
    #SAVE PDB CONTAINING SURFACE RESIDUES :
    #SAVE PDB CONTAINING SURFACE RESIDUES (see my_saves above from https://sourceforge.net/p/pymol/mailman/message/29103774/:        
            
    my_save('surface.pdb' , sele, ' '.join([_i for _i in stored.residues]))
    
cmd.extend("print_locals", print_locals)
```

if you load for example `2lyz.pdb` in **pymol** and run the script, calling:

`findSurfaceResidues(doShow=1, quiet =0)` will show:

[image]

and will save file `surface.txt` :

```
2lyz
1            LYS
2            VAL
3            PHE
4            GLY
5            ARG
6            CYS
7            GLU
10           ALA
11           ALA
12           MET
13           LYS
14           ARG
.............
```

and file `surface.pdb` :

```
################
##2lyz
################
ATOM      1  N   LYS A   1       3.246  10.041  10.379  1.00  5.28           N  
ATOM      2  CA  LYS A   1       2.386  10.407   9.247  1.00  7.90           C  
ATOM      3  C   LYS A   1       2.462  11.927   9.098  1.00  7.93           C  
ATOM      4  O   LYS A   1       2.582  12.668  10.097  1.00  6.28           O  
ATOM      5  CB  LYS A   1       0.946   9.964   9.482  1.00  3.54           C  
ATOM      6  CG  LYS A   1      -0.045  10.455   8.444  1.00  3.75           C  
ATOM      7  CD  LYS A   1      -1.470  10.062   8.818  1.00  2.85           C  
ATOM      8  CE  LYS A   1      -2.354   9.922   7.589  1.00  3.83           C  
ATOM      9  NZ  LYS A   1      -3.681   9.377   7.952  1.00  1.78           N1+
ATOM     10  N   VAL A   2       2.383  12.351   7.847  1.00  9.08           N  
ATOM     11  CA  VAL A   2       2.387  13.773   7.480  1.00  9.24           C  
ATOM     12  C   VAL A   2       0.998  14.050   6.903  1.00  6.36           C  
.............
```